# Obtaining predictions from linear model

Tags: r, linear-model

This is probably a pretty simple question, but I have been having some trouble interpreting the documentation for the `predict` function.

I am generating a simple linear model from a data frame containing (X, Y) pairs, which I would then like to use to predict Y given new X. My code looks something like this:

```
my_lm = lm(Y ~ X, data=my_data)
new_Y = predict(my_lm, new_data, interval="confidence", type="response")
print(new_Y[,'fit'])
```

This does seem to give me values already, but I am a bit confused about the `type` parameter. The documentation only mentions that `type` specifies "response or model term", but it doesn't say what that actually means. Searching the web for examples I have seen both methods mentioned on different sites, with no clear explanation why they were used.

Can someone tell me what the right way to solve my problem is and where I can read up on the actual meaning of the type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `type` argument specifies if you want predictions of the response (the $Y$ variable) or if you want predictions for the individual terms in the model. In combination with the `terms` argument you can get predictions for some or all (default) of the terms. 
In your example, there is just one term in addition to the intercept. Your model is 
$$Y_i = \alpha + \beta X_i + \epsilon_i$$ 
hence, predictions of the terms would give you $\hat{\beta}X^{\text{new}}$ while predictions of the response would give you $\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta}X^{\text{new}}$.

Note that `type = "response"` is the default for `predict.lm`, so you get predictions of responses by default, which I guess is what you would expect from a predict function. If you look at `predict.glm` instead the default is `"link"`, which gives the linear predictors by default, so for generalized linear models you need to be explicit if you want predictions of the response.